# How to permanently disable filter keys in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, ease-of-access

Is it possible to permanently disable the *Filter Keys: Ignore Brief or Repeated Keystrokes* Ease of Access setting in Windows 8?

It seems to be reactivating itself. I'll notice that repeated letters stop registering while typing a document, and it's frustrating to keep returning to the Ease of Access control panel to turn it off again.

I don't think I'm doing anything unusual, apart from being a fairly fast typist.

Comment: You sure the keyboard is not to blame?

Comment: I don't think the keyboard itself could be sending a signal to Windows to turn this setting on, and it seems to be behaving normally otherwise. It's definitely not a flaw in the keyboard itself: the setting in Windows gets turned on, and turning off the setting fixes the problem. It's just aggravating to keep having to do that.

Comment: This a local or domain account we are talking about?  Because I can confirm once the setting is turned off it stays off for me.

Comment: It's a local account ... a personal laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be happening since the keyboard shortcut to activate Filter keys may still be enabled (this is the default).  Under the **Turn on Filter keys** option, click the link that says **Setup Filter Keys**.  Here, uncheck the option **Turn on Filter keys when right SHIFT is pressed for 8 seconds**.

EDIT: Screenshots Added (for Windows  8)
 1. Press <kbd>RSHIFT</kbd> and hold it down for 8 seconds
[image: Shift button pressed 5 times in a row on Windows 8]

2. Click on "Go to the Ease of Access Center" and...
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that there was an additional control panel behind the desktop interface, in addition to the one behind the metro interface.