# Repeated keypresses are ignored

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard, input

So, I'm having trouble fixing my brothers computer.

The problem is that if I try to press a key more than once in succession every keypress but the first is ignored.

Holding a key down works as expected.

---

After looking this up it would seem it's the "Filter Keys" option that causes this but I have tried

- Disabling all keyboard related "Accessibility" options
- Setting the "Accessibility" options flags in the registry
- renaming the "Accessibility" key in the registry to disable all accessibility
  options

The problem is still not resolved, persists after reboot and occurs as early as the login screen.

I'm quite positive that this isn't a problem with the laptop keyboard as the same behaviour occurs with the on-screen keyboard.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell [which options](http://superuser.com/questions/732291/how-to-permanently-disable-filter-keys-in-windows-8) and registry keys you have modified exactly. Also, try to create a new user and check if the problem persists for the new user as well.

Comment: All options in "make the keyboard easier to use" are disabled. ie. 'Mouse Keys' disabled, 'Sticky Keys' disabled, 'Toggle Keys' disabled, 'Filter Keys' disabled. Modified registry keys: StickyKeys\Flags = 506, KeyboardResponse\Flags = 122, ToggleKeys\Flags = 58, (all of these are located in [HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\]. The issue persists for a newly created user as well.

Comment: Quite frankly I'm out of ideas, so I'll just upvote to make your question more visible to others.

Comment: one of your keys which dont print anything on the screen "might be" stuck in pressed state. if you can't find it you'll need to replace your keyboard. 

I don't expect it to be a software problem.