# How to remove accessibility in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, accessibility

On Windows 8.1, is there a way to remove the accessibility features completely?

I don't use them, and they are very annoying (eg. sticky keys and the like that keep popping up out of nowhere). In previous versions, you used to be able to disable it through `Windows Features` under `Programs and Features`. But in Windows 8.1, I see the following:

[image]

Comment: "In previous versions, you used to be able to disable it through Windows Features under Programs and Features."  This is what's tripping you up; that's not how you disable sticky keys and such in previous versions.

Comment: In Windows 7 at least, these settings were changed from Control Panel -> Accessibility. I permanently disabled Sticky Keys from launching when I pressed shift 5 times in a row, since I do this a lot with gaming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently disable filter keys in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/732291/how-to-permanently-disable-filter-keys-in-windows-8)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's not, I want to remove all accessibility not just filter keys.